# java: execution order messed up without multithreading involved

Tags: java, jvm, order-of-execution

```
//Pseudocode

class A
{
//......

b.method1();
b.method1();
b.method1();

b.method2();
b.method2();
b.method2();

//......
}

class B{
//......
method1(){
    log("m1 called {} {}",this.hashCode(),currentThreadId)
}

method2(){
    log("m2 called {} {}",this.hashCode(),currentThreadId)
}
//......
}
```

**expected**: 3 lines of m1 log, followed by 3 m2 log

**actual**: sometimes m2 log gets printed in between m1 logs

this only happens on **one** of my colleague's **machine**, not anyone else's

and even on his machine, it only happens like **2 or 3 times out of 10 attempts**

when the execution order gets messed up, we have looked at the log, the object of B **hash code** is **the same** and the **thread id** is **the same**.

so, it's **inside one thread**, **on one object**, the **execution order is getting messed up**.

I am only showing Pseudocode here, not the actual full code, because even with the real code, I can not get it to stably reproduce the problem on other machines.

is there any reason why this would be happening? is there any hidden jvm secret that could be causing this?

the jdk used on my colleague's machine is 1.8.0_131. it's the same on my machine, but mine can not reproduce the problem.

2020-09-21 update

added stack trace info into the log line in m2,

it shows that each time m2 is called, in the stack trace it's caller is the line that is calling m1 in ClassA

Comment: Please show the `log` method.

Comment: could that be because of log library you use ? Do you know if it is syncronized?

Comment: @AndyTurner it's was log4j

Comment: @cool I think log4j get the thread id from the thread that it was called by